# How to pass NSObject to cpp code in objective c

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to integrate cpp code with Objective-C. At some point I want to use NSObject instance in cpp like below :

```
class Data
{

    NSObject* mParent;

    public void SetParent(NSObject* parent)
    {
        mParent = parent;
    }

    public void SayHello()
    {
         [mParent sayHello:@"World"];
    }
};
```

It is possible to do this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's entirely possible to do this, but you'll have to compile your code as Objective-C++, and not C++.  ARC also requires that you manually manage the memory of pointers in structures and POD classes, so it's required (and recommended even when you aren't warned) that you mark the Objective-C pointer's type with `__unsafe_unretained`.

Comment: I know about .mm file extension for Objective-C++. I am facing issue when I am trying to mention NSObject member variable in .h file. I tried to add #include <Foundation/Foundation.h> but when compiling, it throws lots of error. any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

That level of integration can only be achieved by making that an Objective-C class and using Objective-C++ (i.e. change the file extension to `.mm`).

You can never have a C++ class calling Objective-C in that way.